# Edit LEX Opportunity Stages

Tags: lightning, opportunity, lightning-experience

Where can I edit the opportunity stages in LEX? I feel like I am going crazy. I can't find it anywhere. I have checked in All setup, Object Builder, Opportunities, Sales Path, Sales Processes.... everywhere I could think it might be.

Comment: Do you mean managing stages instead of edit?

Comment: Yes. Well, either, really. How do I create or manage the stages for opportunities? @RahulSharma

Comment: The field is called StageName at it is a field on the Opportunity so you will need to manipulate that value

Comment: This I understand, @Eric, but where do I find that field to edit? I have looked all though the object for this field. I cannot find it.

Comment: You are going to need to provide more context. Via API the field is `Opportunity.StageName` if you in LEX UI you can use the Stage path at the top to edit it. If you are in a different context you will need to provide us with more information

Comment: I am trying to create a new sales process. Part of that process is selecting the opportunity stages that apply to that process. I do not want the default stages, I want to create my own stages. In classic you can edit this by Setup > Customize > Opportunities > Fields and then finding the Stage field. You can then replace or edit the StageName values. 
I cannot find where to do this in LEX. This is not for a specific opportunity.

Comment: @Eric apparently not all the fields are shown on one page. I am an idiot, grrrr. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The master list is found in All Setup > Objects and Fields > Opportunity > Stage. If you use Record Types (found in the Opportunity area, as above), you also need to look at All Setup > Feature Settings > Sales > Sales Processes. This allows you to select a sublist of all master values per record type.

Comment: ....I was typing out a reply to your answer about how it isn't there.... and I just noticed not all the fields are displayed on a single page. There is the "next" button. I am an idiot. But thank you.

Comment: @Chance - You the field listing is a complete shift from what we were used to and it is not apparent by the UI that the Next/Previous is even there. Not a very friendly UI in that respect. When it first was there took me a bit to notice the next and previous pages and I was like "Where are all my fields"

Comment: @Chance Yeah, it's unfortunate. That said, there is a handy "search box" at the top of the page that you could use to find a specific field. I hardly ever actually scroll through the list anymore.